# NPX create-react-app creating other folders

Tags: create-react-app, npx

So whenever i use

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

it generates outside the folder "my-app" a lot of others folders such as **_locks**, **_npx**, **_cacache** and a json file named **anonymous-cli-metrics**.

I tried changing the cache location, but I couldn't do it, I want to use the command without creating these files does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this same problem. You should **install** your nodejs on your **c:/ directory**. Uninstall nodejs and remove cache files and remove the PATH variable and reinstall it in your **C:/ directory.**
Another possible problem is with **chocolatey**, if you've installed **along with** nodejs you should remove that also and do a **fresh install** on your **root** directory
Or try setting yout npm cache to,

```
npm config set cache C:\cache
```